# How to add spaces between RecycledView items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a recycledview that has spaces separating the contents of the list to make it look cleaner. I currently have it looking like this...

```
Paul
John
Adam
Susan
Sherry
```

But would like it having a little more spacing in between the names for the border to more distinguished.

Comment: you need to add top or bottom margin to items layout

Answer (score 2):

You can padding or margin inside your View

`android:layout_margin="8dp"`
or 
 `android:padding="8dp"`

You can also add divider between the items by `DividerItemDecoration`

`DividerItemDecoration` is a RecyclerView.ItemDecoration that can be used as a divider between items of a LinearLayoutManager.

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
    linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

You can learn more about this here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration

Hope, It will help

Answer (score 0):

if you use the TextView, set padding bottom or top

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding/margin to the recycler view item. You have to create your own custom list item layout and add the required margin/padding to the view in the custom layout. This has to be added to the adapter and adapter has to be set to the recycler view. You can follow the below example to understand the whole fittings required between Recycler View and Adapter

https://medium.com/@hinchman_amanda/working-with-recyclerview-in-android-kotlin-84a62aef94ec